# If two adults agreed to produce a child where one side gets to keep the child, can there be any sort of child support lawsuit?

Tags: child-support

Is there such a contract enforceable by law that would protect the side that parts with the child from being sued for child support by the side that keeps the child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The law varies considerable from place to place, even within the United States.

Some jurisdictions allow sperm donors or egg donors to avoid being treated as legally parents of a child produced with their donation, and surrogacy arrangements using a fertilized egg implanted in a non-genetically related surrogate are also sometimes allowed. These arrangements are called "assisted reproduction" arrangements and prevent paternity from being established in the first place, despite a pregnancy or genetic relationship to the resulting child.

But, outside strict adherence to a statutory safe harbor, usually, both genetic parents of a child will have legal liability to the child, unless there is a termination of parental rights in connection with an adoption.

Once paternity is established and has not be legally terminated, it is almost never possible to reach a legal agreement prospectively prohibiting a child support lawsuit.

Comment: Child support is for the child, not for the parent.